# Auto height of a div with image 100%

Tags: css, image, stretch

I have following layout:

CSS

```
.top-container{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:relative;
}
.top-container img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="top-container">
<img src="blahblah" />
</div>
```

My problem is that i need the image to be width 100% (this is actually working),
but the height must have an auto height because of the 100% width. I have tried with
`height:auto`. But of course that did not help. It helped with a specific height, but then the image is scaled wrongly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jus make a small change in your image css as below:

```
.top-container img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsk8S/)**

Answer (score 3):

try this

use height:`100vh` and remove `100%`;

http://jsfiddle.net/r4y6D/1/

```
.top-container{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:relative;
}
.top-container img{
width:100%;
height:100vh;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.top-container{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:relative;
}
.top-container img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="top-container">
<img src="blahblah" />
</div>
```

I have change `height:100%` to `height:auto` in your coe. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the height is what you are looking for but see below.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nkcsr/1/

```
.top-container{
width:100%;
border: 1px solid black
}
.top-container img{
width: 100%
}
```